# JSON file does NOT display through the data.responseText. Although in Chrome, it's there in the debugger nicely

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Here's my code:

```
var what = "some/url/path..."
$(document).ready(function () {
    var _getInfo = function getInfo(what) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: what,
            crossDomain: true,
            //data: "{}",
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {

                console.log("Data found: " + data.responseText);
            },
            error: function (data) {

                console.log("Data not found: " + data.responseText);
            }
        });
    };

    var retVal = JSON.parse(_getInfo(networksURL));
    console.log("Return Value: " + retVal);
});
```

The JSON object returns nicely under the NETWORKS tab of the debugger... no problems... but... and this is a big but, the JSON object WILL NOT show via the above code in the console.log.  Any thoughts???

Oh yeah, I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u at the line that contains: var retVal = JSON.parse(_getInfo(networksURL));

Thanks

UPDATE:

OK, the error is gone but I'm still getting this in CHROME debugger under the NETWORKS TAB:

0: {id:23ef0d23-0d8d-4466-98da-81ef30791773, networkType:1, controllerIp:10.255.135.22, redirectType:0,…}
controllerIp: "10.255.135.22"
id: "23ef0d23-0d8d-4466-98da-81ef30791773"
name: "n1"
networkCost: 1351
networkType: 1
networkWeight: 64888
notes: "This is a network for network 1"
redirectType: 0
1: {id:8e2822b1-49a8-498e-979b-2849cfa82148, networkType:1, controllerIp:10.255.150.24, redirectType:0,…}
2: {id:678b4a01-a6a6-449f-966d-c50c74964729, networkType:2, controllerIp:10.255.150.22, redirectType:0,…}
3: {id:b4b46748-511a-49bf-9d22-8da014c76cc2, networkType:3, controllerIp:10.255.654.22, redirectType:0,…}

That's what's coming back... perfect, but this is in the CONSOLE LOG:

Data not found: undefined

Any thoughts?

UPDATE AGAIN:

OK, this is what I'm getting now:

0: {id:23ef0d23-0d8d-4466-98da-81ef30791773, networkType:1, controllerIp:10.255.135.22, redirectType:0,…}
1: {id:8e2822b1-49a8-498e-979b-2849cfa82148, networkType:1, controllerIp:10.255.150.24, redirectType:0,…}
2: {id:678b4a01-a6a6-449f-966d-c50c74964729, networkType:2, controllerIp:10.255.150.22, redirectType:0,…}
3: {id:b4b46748-511a-49bf-9d22-8da014c76cc2, networkType:3, controllerIp:10.255.654.22, redirectType:0,…}

Which is the same JSON object above and now this is in the console log:

Data not found: undefined
Return Value:
null
  No Properties

Alright, what I ULTIMATELY need is that JSON object to RETURN through the responseText or data.responseText.

But I believe you're on the right track, so far...Thanks, let's continue

Comment: have you tried to console log just data and not data.responseText

Comment: `var retVal = JSON.parse(_getInfo(networksURL));` doesn't make sense, `_getInfo` doesn't return json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. There's no such thing as synchronous JSONP. *(Well, a couple of older browsers used to have a way to do it, but they've largely been fixed.)* You can use JSONP, or you can do a synchronous ajax call, but you can't do both. Consequently, it's impossible for your `_getInfo` function to return the data as a return value. (You're also missing a `return` statement trying to do that.)

   Instead, remove the `async: false` (it's being ignored anyway) and pass a callback function into `_getInfo`:

   ```
   _getInfo(networksURL, function(data) {
       console.log("Return Value: " + data);
   });
   ```
2. You don't need to use `JSON.parse` with JSONP. The nature of JSONP is such that it will *already* be deserialized (parsed) by the time you see it.
3. You're looking for `data.responseText`, but the argument that the `success` function receives is not an XHR object, it's *the data*. Remove the `.responseText` from that.

So in sum, a minimal update:

```
var what = "some/url/path..."
$(document).ready(function () {
     _getInfo = function getInfo(what, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: what,
            crossDomain: true,
            //data: "{}",
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Data found");
                callback(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Data not found");
                callback(null); // Or whatever you want to use for the error case
            }
        });
    };

    _getInfo(networksURL, function(data) {
        console.log("Return Value: ");
        console.dir(data);
    });
});
```

---

Separately: That named function expression:

```
var _getInfo = function getInfo() {
    // ...
};
```

...is a somewhat advanced construct. If you're not 100% sure that you need it, I'd probably just use a declaration:

```
function getInfo() {
    // ...
}
```

(With or without the `_` at the beginning of the name, your call.)

Comment: TJ - Still not getting data coming through the console log... It's working through the network tab in Chrome's debugger...

Comment: Here's the answer:
 
What TJ suggested works - but after struggling for about 2 hours, I've had to set up Chrome like this: 1) Create a new directory under my documents called: Fake Chrome or whatever... 2) Next create a NEW instance of Chrome with these params in the TARGET field: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\Users\<yourname>\Documents\Fake Chrome Profile"; LEAVE THE START IN: field alone!  Finally under the GENERAL tab rename the Shortcut to: DANGER CHROME NOT SECURE INSIDE ONLY.  DO NOT BROWSE the Internet...

Comment: Or simply set up your server to accept JSONP - which is the problem mainly. We have a server at work that's a LINUX box and runs TOMCAT 6.x... Make sure if you homegrow a server, set it up properly and you will NOT have to do the above to Google Chrome.  Happy programming!